# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException Occurs When Try to Get JSON File as StorageFile

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a very simple UWP app. I just want to get a JSON file as storagable file.
here is the code:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void GetCityButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Uri dataUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Model/sample.json");

        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(dataUri);
    }
}
```

Here is the json file data:

```
{"coord":{"lon":-0.13,"lat":51.51},"weather":[{"id":300,"main":"Drizzle","description":"light intensity drizzle","icon":"09d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":280.32,"pressure":1012,"humidity":81,"temp_min":279.15,"temp_max":281.15},"visibility":10000,"wind":{"speed":4.1,"deg":80},"clouds":{"all":90},"dt":1485789600,"sys":{"type":1,"id":5091,"message":0.0103,"country":"GB","sunrise":1485762037,"sunset":1485794875},"id":2643743,"name":"London","cod":200}
```

Whenever I try to call this click method I get `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`.

But whenever I try to rename it as `sample.txt` it doesn't throw any error.
here is the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Please help me! Why does this happen?

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of the `Model` folder in Solution Explorer and file explorer?

Comment: And also please click on the JSON file and post the properties of the file below, especially the Build action property

Comment: Build action : none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `Build action` is set to `Content` so that the file is included in the app package. Once you do this, the code will work as expected :-) .

Comment: Yeah. got it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple !! Try "build action: content" of the sample.json file property. And then try again to debug. I worked well for me.